# check Return result from function

Tags: jquery

My function 'GetResultById' returns true or false. How can I check the return result from the function in JQuery? I am trying to hide and show RadComboBox depending on the result.
 Here is my code. Also I would like to hide RadComboBox when the page loaded. I put combo.hideDropDown() in Init function but it doesn't seem to be working. Please let me know.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: applicationPath + "/test/Test.svc/GetResultById",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{"sId":' + sender.get_value() + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result)
             {
                  if(result == true)
                  {
                     combo.hideDropdown();
                  }
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a service in ASP and an AJAX call, I believe the results are *always* passed back in the "d" property. That is to say your callback on an AJAX success will have the "actual" result in `result.d` property, not just `result`.

e.g.

```
success: function(result){
  alert(result.d); // actual return result
}
```

*(Or it may be ".d", I honestly forget right now, but either way "result" alone (I don't believe) has the result)*

#### Update

it appears [I was right](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2009/01/15/jquery-json-and-aspnet/) about the logic, not the property. `result.d` will have your return result.

Comment: if(result.d == false) is working but it doesn't hide the ComboBox. It looks like .hideDropDown() is not working. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing what `hideDropDown` contains I'm afraid I can't be of more help. Also, as @Maximilian recommended, I would use a string comparison (surround `false` in quotes). Can you maybe update your question with the code in the `hideDropDown` function?

Comment: Alright. Also, try using `combo.hide()` or `$(combo).hide()` (likewise with `.show()`) and see if that works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the result will not be delivered as a boolian but as a string. therefore you have to check for result == "true"...

Answer (score 0):

If you use any ajax function in asynchronous mode, you will not return a value that calls the function depending of the result of the consultation as the call is asynchronous.

to display and hide something you can use jQuery.ajax events:

beforeSend
complete (or "error" and "success")

[Documentation of jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

The best is to **debug with Firebug**. It could very well be that your JSON serialization framework you use on the server, doesn't output the boolean directly, but as a field of an object instead.